# Python Beeware Briefcase Git SHA issue

Tags: python, git, sha, pyenv, beeware

I'm trying to teach myself to use the beeware briefcase package for Python, although having issues setting it up. I've got pyenv installed, and my local python version in the root of my project is set to 3.8.9. I'm using windows and Powershell

In PowerShell, I've created the python virtual environment, and have installed briefcase via pip.

I've installed git as well, and linked the repo to github.

When I try to run "briefcase new", and go through the prompts, I receive the following traceback (for both powershell and gitbash):

(I've removed my root details in below errors)

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\~\.pyenv\pyenv-win\versions\3.8.9\lib\runpy.py", line 194, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "C:\~\.pyenv\pyenv-win\versions\3.8.9\lib\runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\~\CodeProjects\beeware-tutorial\.venv\Scripts\briefcase.exe\__main__.py", line 7, in <module>
  File "c:\~\codeprojects\beeware-tutorial\.venv\lib\site-packages\briefcase\__main__.py", line 14, in main
    command(**options)
  File "c:\~\codeprojects\beeware-tutorial\.venv\lib\site-packages\briefcase\commands\new.py", line 537, in __call__
    return self.new_app(template=template, **options)
  File "c:\~\codeprojects\beeware-tutorial\.venv\lib\site-packages\briefcase\commands\new.py", line 488, in new_app
    cached_template = self.update_cookiecutter_cache(
  File "c:\~\codeprojects\beeware-tutorial\.venv\lib\site-packages\briefcase\commands\base.py", line 569, in update_cookiecutter_cache
    f"Using existing template (sha {head.commit.hexsha}, "
  File "c:\~\codeprojects\beeware-tutorial\.venv\lib\site-packages\git\refs\symbolic.py", line 217, in _get_commit
    obj = self._get_object()
  File "c:\~\codeprojects\beeware-tutorial\.venv\lib\site-packages\git\refs\symbolic.py", line 210, in _get_object
    return Object.new_from_sha(self.repo, hex_to_bin(self.dereference_recursive(self.repo, self.path)))
  File "c:\~\codeprojects\beeware-tutorial\.venv\lib\site-packages\git\objects\base.py", line 85, in new_from_sha
    oinfo = repo.odb.info(sha1)
  File "c:\~\codeprojects\beeware-tutorial\.venv\lib\site-packages\git\db.py", line 43, in info
    hexsha, typename, size = self._git.get_object_header(bin_to_hex(binsha))
  File "c:\~\codeprojects\beeware-tutorial\.venv\lib\site-packages\git\cmd.py", line 1253, in get_object_header
    return self.__get_object_header(cmd, ref)
  File "c:\~\codeprojects\beeware-tutorial\.venv\lib\site-packages\git\cmd.py", line 1240, in __get_object_header
    return self._parse_object_header(cmd.stdout.readline())
  File "c:\~\codeprojects\beeware-tutorial\.venv\lib\site-packages\git\cmd.py", line 1198, in _parse_object_header
    raise ValueError("SHA could not be resolved, git returned: %r" % (header_line.strip()))
ValueError: SHA could not be resolved, git returned: b''
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure how I managed to fix the issue but I uninstalled git version 2.37.1 and installed git version 2.30.2, used GitBash to create a new environment, and installed a briefcase.

Seems to have solved the issue.